# Keyboard layout toggle key combination not working

Tags: debian, x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I created the file `00-keyboard.conf` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` with the following options:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        Option "XkbLayout" "latam,ru"
    Option "XkbVariant" ",qwerty"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```

The output from `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is

```
[    29.431] (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    29.431] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HP Wireless hotkeys'
[    29.431] (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: always reports core events
[    29.432] (**) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
[    29.432] (--) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[    29.432] (--) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Found keys
[    29.432] (II) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[    29.432] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input9/event8"
[    29.432] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP Wireless hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 15)
[    29.432] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    29.432] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.432] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "latam,ru"
[    29.432] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ",qwerty"
[    29.432] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
[   459.494] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 902
[   459.494] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   459.494] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.40  1366 1402 1450 1610  768 771 776 790 +hsync -vsync (47.5 kHz eP)
[   459.494] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   50.93  1366 1402 1450 1610  768 771 776 790 +hsync -vsync (31.6 kHz e)
```

This is the output from `localectl status`

```
System Locale: LANG=es_CL.UTF-8
                  LANGUAGE=es_CL:es
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: latam
       X11 Model: pc105
```

Pressing Alt + Shift does nothing. I am in Debian Jessie.

However, `setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle latam,ru` works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `setxkbmap` and then the keybinding works, you can execute the command when you start the session. This works for me in Openbox: i've included the command in `~/.config/openbox/autostart`:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:­scroll latam,ru
```

You can change the keys combination of course. The full list:

```
grep "grp:.*toggle" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```

And to see the current configuration of your keyboard:

```
setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
```